# Plotting distances between individuals within a group and a focal animal using R

Tags: r, plot, distance

I have been checking this great post ([Plotting group distances in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222267/plotting-group-distances-in-r)) and I was wondering whether someone had the problem to plot distances between subject and a focal point (e.g. a focal animal) within a group. We are collecting data on the distance between group members within a group with respect to a focal subject. I was looking for ideas about how to plot the individual distances from the focal subject and to show standard deviations. In my mind, I have a plot like this one: [an example with 5 subjects, a focal subject in the center and four group mates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHW1f.png)

My data are organized as follows (e.g.; F is the focal animal in this observation, BCDA are the group mates observed, distance in meters is reported):

```
FOCAL   B   F   C   D   A
F   6   NA  10  4   3
F   10  NA  10  5   5
F   6   NA  10  6   5
F   6   NA  10  8   5
F   6   NA  10  2   5
F   2   NA  11  2   5
F   2   NA  11  2   5
F   2   NA  NA  2   3
F   1   NA  3   NA  1
F   2   NA  NA  5   3
F   2   NA  NA  2   3
F   1   NA  NA  2   5
F   1   NA  6   2   5
F   1   NA  8   2   5
F   1   NA  9   2   NA
F   1   NA  4   2   5
F   1   NA  7   2   5
F   1   NA  7   2   5
F   1   NA  7   2   5
```

Thanks for your help and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite what you asked for, but one idea would be to use `ggplot` and polar coordinates.  You might want to play around with different options.  I quite like the violin plot, for example...

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% select(A, B, C, D) %>%         #select the variables of interest
  gather(key=id, value=dist) %>%      #convert to long format
  ggplot(aes(x=id, y=dist)) +
  geom_violin() +
  coord_polar(theta = "x")
```

[image]

Or you could try a boxplot, or plot the means and deviations separately, or whatever works for you.

HOWEVER - Bear in mind the distorting effect of the polar coordinates - they can be hard to interpret visually. You might well get a more readable and representative chart by sticking with rectangular coordinates.

Comment: I believe this is a great visualization for relative distributions between "edges" (A, B, C, D).

Comment: Thanks. Excellent idea!